# Badische / pfälzische Partikel "her": Was ist das?

Tags: etymology, dialect, particle

Im (kur)pfälzischen und badischen Dialekt (ich glaube auch im Saarländischen) gibt es die Partikel "her", die in jeden zweiten Satz am Stammtisch eingefügt werden muß - Sie gibt u.A. Empörung oder Erstaunen wieder und dient der Verstärkung der Argumentation.

> Her, die hän mir mei Rente kürzt, so e Sauerei!

Was es *bedeutet* glaube ich also zu wissen - Doch wo kommt es *her*?

1. Von "schau mal *her*"
2. vom Ausruf "*He!*"
3. von *hör* mal her
4. eine Herkunft ähnlich dem britischen "hear, hear" ("genausoisses", "hört, hört"). Das wäre leicht unterschiedlich zu (3)
5. Was ganz anderes?

Wikipedia hat unter "kurpfälzische Dialekte" den Eintrag

> Her!, bzw. Hea! - als Ausfruf, ähnlich dem sonst üblichen „He!“ verwendet

ein badisches Mundartlexikon (Karlsruher Stadt-Wiki) meint dazu

> her he (empört). Dies ist das vielleicht typischste Wort breitester Karlsruher Umgangssprache: „Mensch, her, her, jetz' her mer mol zu!“ – ebenso typisch und für Auswärtige unmöglich auszusprechen wie das oi in „zwoi woiche Ooier“

was mir aber beides bei meiner Frage nicht (sehr) viel weiter hilft. Das zweite Zitat deutet deutlich(?) auf "hör". Ehrlich gesagt, bin ich mir nicht mal sicher, ob das badische und das pfälzische Wort dasselbe ist, nehme es aufgrund der räumlichen Nachbarschaft aber stark an.

Comment: Ich kann die Frage zwar nicht beantworten, weil ich diesen Dialekt nicht kenne, aber ich kenne das Wort »heast«, mit dem in manchen Gegenden Ostösterreichs jeder zweite Satz begonnen wird, vor allem, wenn man sich über etwas aufregt. Dieses »heast« ist definitiv von »hörst du« abgeleitet, daher vermute ich dasselbe für das pfälzische »her«. Vor allem in Wien wurde das »heast« aber schon lange von »oida« (Attwenger haben sogar einen Song mit diesem Titel produziert: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRtdT8SYZOY) Dieses Wort stammt von »Alter« ab, mit dem einen »Hawara« (Freund) anspricht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich stimme dem zu, bis auf das Wort "abgeleitet". Vielleicht war es nicht beabsichtigt, aber es ist irreführend weil Bairische und andere Dialekte nicht vom Deutschen abgeleitet ist, sondern sich nebeneinander her entwickelt und sich gegenseitig beeinflusst haben. Ich will wirklich kein Erbsenzähler sein, aber ich will dass der weit verbreitete Irrglaube "Bairisch ist nur ein Standard Deutscher Dialekt" verschwindet.

Comment: Gibt es überhaupt einen "Standard Deutscher Dialekt" (außer vielleicht Sächsisch)?

Comment: @tofro hab mich unglücklich ausgedrückt, ich habe gemeint "Dialekt des Standard Deutschen". Ich denke man könnte Dänisch, Niederländisch, etc. als "Standard Deutschen Dialekt" bezeichnen ;)

Answer (score 2):

Laut [Pfälzischem Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=PfWB&lemid=PH02655):

> Artikelverweis  her2: imperative Bildung zu PfWB her1. Heʳ emol! 'Gib
>   her!' [KU-Kaulb, verbr.], Heʳ 'n! 'Gib ihn her!' [verbr.] Heʳ's emol!
>   'Reiche es her!' [verbr., Kühn Hamet 113]. Heʳ mit'm Geld! [verbr.].
>   Stock heʳ! Androhung von Schlägen [Kaislt]. Her's her! 'Gib es her!'
>   [verbr. Gal]. Heʳ's emol here! [Kaislt].

Also her im Sinne von hierher.

Ob es im badischen gleich/ähnlich ist, weiß ich nicht.

Comment: bin nicht sicher, ob wir dasselbe Wort meinen.

Comment: Ich finde da jedenfalls kein "Hör". Findest Du etwas anderes, das passen könnte?

Comment: s.o., zweites Zitat *deutet* zumindest darauf hin - das dritte *her* im Beispielsatz heißt eindeutig "hör" - Was natürlich nicht beweist, das es die ersten beiden auch tun...

Comment: In welchem Beispielsatz sind 3 *her*?

Comment: Ich meinte natürlich **meine** Beispiele in der Frage: *„Mensch, her (1), her (2), jetz' her (3) mer mol zu!“*

Comment: Ja, da differenziert Deine Schreibweise nicht. Ohne fremde Quelle und sorgfältige Notation bleibt da nur Spekulation. Zum dritten her hast Du aber ja keine Frage, da bist Du Dir ja sicher. Hier http://woerterbuchnetz.de/ sind noch mehr Wörterbücher (Rheinisch, Elsässisch, ...) - vielleicht magst Du selbst weitersuchen.